# Allow only images & pdf in UiDocument Picker Swift 3

Tags: pdf, swift3, uidocumentpickervc

I need the user to select only images and pdf files from UIDocumentPicker & want to check which type of file user has selected in the DocumentPicker delegate method

I have used this but this allow everything

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.content","public.data"], in: .import)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.composite-content"], in: .import)
```

this will only allow pdf files to import

Comment: It allows doc files as well. Any solution, So it selects only PDF not any other type.

Comment: @Tina 
import CoreServices

Then Enter types like this


let _ = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Services for this work

import CoreServices

Then Enter types like this

let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String, kUTTypePNG as String, kUTTypeJPEG as String], in: .import)

Or without Core Services

let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.adobe.pdf", "public.png", "public.jpeg"], in: .import)